# Building a dynamic projection for EF (to dynamically select columns)

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

In my team, I was asked to develop some kind of 'generic dashboard' that we can use for a lot of places in our application.

Basically, what they want the user to be able to do is make a column and filter selection on a set of data and save that filter.

Now on some data sets, the amount of columns reaches well over 100. Naturally, I don't want to get all of these from our data layer. We are using Entity Framework 5.0 on top of SQL Server at the moment.

Now, my plan was to make some kind of object to represent the column selection and filter. Translating the filters to an EF query, so the where clauses and sorting will be correct should not be a problem (build predicates dynamically or generate entitySQL). The part that I can't wrap my mind around is how I can do a dynamic field selection. As I said, I don't want to fetch any data I'm not going to return.

So, how do I go from a list of column names to a data projection I can use?

Comment: Take a collection of fields names and fetch them at run-time using reflection.

Comment: have you read (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)